# Finite cyclic group having exactly one non-trivial subgroup has order square of a prime.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

> Let $G$ be a finite cyclic group such that $G$ has an unique non trivial subgroup. Claim is  to show that $G$ is of order $p^2,$ for some prime $p.$

I tried in the following way,

The possible orders of $G$ are either prime or product of primes(thanks to number theory).
since $|G|$ can't be prime here, it should be product of primes.

Suppose  $|G|$ is $pq,$ where $p$ and $q$ are two distinct primes. Then there exist two non trivial subgroups of order $p$ and $q$ (thanks to cauchy), a contradiction. So $|G|$  should be  $p^2,$ for some prime $p.$ Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's very close, but you've left out the cases $|G|=pqr, |G|=p^2q, |G|=pqrst$...and so on. So instead of assuming $|G|=pq$ you should assume $pq$ divides $|G|$, and see how you have to adapt your argument. You also need to check that $|G|$ can't be $p^k$ for $k>2$.

Comment: suppose $|G|$ is $p^k,k>2$. Since a cyclic group has subgroups of order $d$, where $d$ is a divisor of $|G|$, $G$ has more than one non trivial subgroups (of orders $p ,p^2,\dots, p^{k-1}$), a contradiction. So $|G|$ can't be $p^k,k>2$. the same argument is valid for other cases too.. is this correct?

Comment: Yeah, your second sentence is the necessary point.